# Can't order data frame by index. Pandas df .value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame with a month column whose count I'm trying to calculate using the following method:

```
df[['Month']].value_counts()
```

This method returns:

```
Month
5.0      1402
9.0      1375
8.0      1273
10.0     1188
7.0      1136
6.0       801
11.0      801
4.0       651
dtype: int64
```

I want to use the .tolist() method on this dataframe but want to order it and can't figure out how to order the dataframe by month, that is, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can `.sort_index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) you can use arg. `sort` to control the output. The default value is `True`, but if `False` then it would most likely be sorted by the index (although I can't seem to find it in the docs).

```
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 12, 30), columns=['mycol']).value_counts(sort=False)
```

You can always use [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) as well and that's probably a safer approach

```
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 12, 30), columns=['mycol']).value_counts().sort_index()
```

Comment: why did you mention that using sort_index() is safer option.

Comment: @gilf0yle just because I couldn't find anything in the docs assuring that index is **always** sorted when `sort` is False.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Alex Newman's answer.

You can also do this

```
series=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 12, 30), columns=['mycol']).value_counts()
```

this returns a Series
mycol

```
0        6
6        5
9        4
2        3
8        2
7        2
5        2
4        2
1        2
11       1
10       1
dtype: int64
```

then you can simply sort that using `Series.sort_index()`

```
series.sort_index()

mycol
0        6
1        2
2        3
4        2
5        2
6        5
7        2
8        2
9        4
10       1
11       1
```

this code is self explanatory, for efficient and compact form of code you can use Alex Newman's code.